# Disappearing meta chatroom

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, per-site-meta

*(I previously asked this question at [Mathematics Educators meta](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/528/77), where [this answer](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/a/529/77) suggested that I report it as a bug here on the main meta.)*

I regularly visit the [Mathematics Educators chatrooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=matheducators.stackexchange.com) and I used to see three.  But starting last March 16, 2017, the [Mathematics Educators Meta chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19867/mathematics-educators-meta) disappeared from the list.  (Clicking the "[Show frozen/deleted rooms](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&nohide=true&host=matheducators.stackexchange.com)" button doesn't reveal it.)  The room is still active and posts there can be seen and made.

Why did this room disappear from the list?

Comment: Martin Sleziak's answer suggests that this bug might be related to recent changes of URLs for per site metas.

Comment: Related: [Why can meta sites be parents of chatrooms?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277349/177408)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks; this was an oversight. To repeat my response from the mathematics educators post:

Sorry about that; this was fallout from the https switchover; the chat rooms hadn't had their individual hosts updated to reflect the "meta.*.stackexchange.com" => "*.meta.stackexchange.com" switch - so it was applying the wrong filter. I've now fixed this. Thanks for reporting it.

[image]